# esp32 x509 over GPRS to AWS MQTT (8883)

Tags: amazon-web-services, x509, esp32, aws-iot

i am new to iot and aws, i am facing a problem communicating with aws mqtt over gsm module

first i used an example to communicate with AWS MQTT using a WIFI library by setting the private,root,and certificate, using wifi client like this

```
  wiFiClient.setCACert(rootCA);// GSM security API or GSM x509 certificate
  wiFiClient.setCertificate(certificate_pem_crt);
  wiFiClient.setPrivateKey(private_pem_key);
```

but now i want to use GSM module instead of wifi for communication
so can any one help me with how to set these x509 codes with GSM client instead of WIFI client?

**in other words the substitute of the above 3 lines of code by using GSM module**

if there are any examples or documents or direct answers

following ia part of my code :

```
/* ESP32 AWS IoT
 *  
 * Simplest possible example (that I could come up with) of using an ESP32 with AWS IoT.
 *  
 * Author: Anthony Elder 
 * License: Apache License v2
 */
//#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> // install with Library Manager, I used v2.6.0

//const char* ssid = "Labospace";
//const char* password = "Labospace20";
const char* awsEndpoint = "myurl.us-east-2.amazonaws.com";

//*****Author: Saja Saleem 
#include <Arduino.h>        // arduino library (optional)
#include <DHTesp.h>         // Library for DHT
#include <SPI.h>            // Library for SPI communication
#include <TinyGPS++.h>      // Library for GPS
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DHT.h>            // Library for DHT
#include "SD_File_Record.h" // Library with SD card functions
#include <ArduinoJson.h>


#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800 // definition of the modem used (SIM800L)
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>    // library with GSM commands
HardwareSerial SerialGSM(1);  // SIM800L serial communication object
TinyGsm modemGSM(SerialGSM);  // library object with GSM functions
TinyGsmClient client(modemGSM);//Create TinyGSM client instances

#define DHTPIN 25             //D15 of ESP32 DevKit
#define DHTTYPE DHT11         // DHT 11
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

TinyGPSPlus gps;             // The TinyGPS object
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
SoftwareSerial gpss(0,21);  // The serial connection to the GPS device
String gpsData="";


// String that will be written to the txt file
String configLine,recordLine;

String reUpLoadData;

// serial speed of both the SIM800L and the serial monitor
const int BAUD_RATE = 9600;

// variables used to count time without crashing the loop function
// millis of reference
long int millisRefCon, millisUserResp;

// flag indicating the time count (used by the 'timeout' function)
bool flagCon = false, flagUserResp = false;

// pins where RX / TX where the SIM800L will be connected
const int  RX_PIN = 2, TX_PIN = 4;

// ESP32-WROOM
#define TFT_DC 12     // A0
#define TFT_CS 13     // CS
#define TFT_MOSI 14   // SDA
#define TFT_CLK 27    // SCK                
#define TFT_RST 0     // RESET
#define TFT_MISO 0    // MISO

const int MICROSD_PIN_CHIP_SELECT = 5; // Pino serial
const int MICROSD_PIN_MOSI = 23;       // Pino serial
const int MICROSD_PIN_MISO = 19;       // Pino serial
const int MICROSD_PIN_SCK = 18;        // Clock pin

//Access point 
const char *APN = "";
// User, if it doesn't exist, leave it empty
const char *USER = "";
// Password, if not, leave empty
const char *PASSWORD = "";

// number of cell phones,that will receive messages and calls and will be able to send SMS commands
 String number = "+972593679079";

float temperature;
const int soundGate = 27; 
float  soundGateValue;
String arrOfStr [18];
String msg;
bool flag=true;


// Variable that stores an error message in the event of a problem with the SD card
String errorMsg;

// Instantiate an SD_File_Record object by sending the file name and the maximum size of the records (not counting the \ r \ r) in the constructor, that is, the actual size will be 3 + 2 = 5
SD_File_Record ObjSD( "s.txt");
//*****


// Update the two certificate strings below. Paste in the text of your AWS 
// device certificate and private key. Add a quote character at the start
// of each line and a backslash, n, quote, space, backslash at the end 
// of each line:

// xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt
const char* certificate_pem_crt = \

"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIDWjCCAkKgAwIBAgIVAIyLqQv38ap5b/mlN74946CuYoEIMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB\n" \
"CwUAME0xSzBJBgNVBAsMQkFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMgTz1BbWF6b24uY29t\n" \
"IEluYy4gTD1TZWF0dGxlIFNUPVdhc2hpbmd0b24gQz1VUzAeFw0yMDA4MTkwMzIz\n" \
"MjFaFw00OTEyMzEyMzU5NTlaMB4xHDAaBgNVBAMME0FXUyBJb1QgQ2VydGlmaWNh\n" \
"dGUwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDlbSHE7CkQNwxB0Esk\n" \
"g2OSmRaORD4hcLsusAEa1/7kxzWnvUFYUiVHNHF85Lmr/uf5fM6R0nfshd5ezemn\n" \
"9277Kl6ELSfxpqpHMSQwVT5G34GtJQhVsqN1lprYqCoaD7zBxtvsRBT4ovTvSGKF\n" \
"YX12c19shM1aaN3r8qxooYBKxKd0ViAjPinlNzXknEzzU9xc50kMdBkuLtNFIe4x\n" \
"RUPOPKmoNi/N0DxxW6wsXG4OMD6SKAMCo/z7jqm3pXQtHojLtmY7PXc/zQeb4Epj\n" \
"c6fiUA9oqSMB6SIWTVdvU/QstY0Fyrtmr6O2iGxeKTREU/WfJDrdVAOBIEofQaCe\n" \
"4H73AgMBAAGjYDBeMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFJLvcxjxXLvXCMCRWITgoz9wFW2LMB0G\n" \
"A1UdDgQWBBSBjEdVFqD43lzK8q85f4S70ig07jAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMA4GA1Ud\n" \
"DwEB/wQEAwIHgDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAJJAFriwrAhAE2dh5mKisXwPo\n" \
"aRexLGO1Xn8x8hDMXF/COYyN+QXX7/+/gakG/gxCGXrxNVAflUJeNBvrP032DWUB\n" \
"dWKZKMpUy+wN3eDRXVYw5Q1eGJNYIhHPTuj/xUucGyhZjWfP2BeD7ZbCQ9ZcxgsS\n" \
"0r2DolZ/0iYZsfsDEOp1DubkuVRWmDh8/4zrs9CC1dl6cZfsm3Z/y+9+1WiSDTgd\n" \
"194SlQqkpSA7Q27OyPcYUM399H8HMbL4NpfMF8S8x0N0LyKC72PZCU+zbQkxbs2q\n" \
"FA4vFGizf1HLL4pflUrUnzVMtuZ/KWlV7mTv9mP3cHlP6jIesLnucQTjTGfdOg\n" \
"//-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

// xxxxxxxxxx-private.pem.key
const char* private_pem_key = \

"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" \
".... my private key goes here ...\n" \
"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";



/* root CA can be downloaded in:
  https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem
*/
const char* rootCA = \

"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIDQTCCAimgAwIBAgITBmyfz5m/jAo54vB4ikPmljZbyjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n" \
"ADA5MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEPMA0GA1UEChMGQW1hem9uMRkwFwYDVQQDExBBbWF6\n" \
"b24gUm9vdCBDQSAxMB4XDTE1MDUyNjAwMDAwMFoXDTM4MDExNzAwMDAwMFowOTEL\n" \
"MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDzANBgNVBAoTBkFtYXpvbjEZMBcGA1UEAxMQQW1hem9uIFJv\n" \
"b3QgQ0EgMTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBALJ4gHHKeNXj\n" \
"ca9HgFB0fW7Y14h29Jlo91ghYPl0hAEvrAIthtOgQ3pOsqTQNroBvo3bSMgHFzZM\n" \
"9O6II8c+6zf1tRn4SWiw3te5djgdYZ6k/oI2peVKVuRF4fn9tBb6dNqcmzU5L/qw\n" \
"IFAGbHrQgLKm+a/sRxmPUDgH3KKHOVj4utWp+UhnMJbulHheb4mjUcAwhmahRWa6\n" \
"VOujw5H5SNz/0egwLX0tdHA114gk957EWW67c4cX8jJGKLhD+rcdqsq08p8kDi1L\n" \
"93FcXmn/6pUCyziKrlA4b9v7LWIbxcceVOF34GfID5yHI9Y/QCB/IIDEgEw+OyQm\n" \
"jgSubJrIqg0CAwEAAaNCMEAwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMC\n" \
"AYYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFIQYzIU07LwMlJQuCFmcx7IQTgoIMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA\n" \
"A4IBAQCY8jdaQZChGsV2USggNiMOruYou6r4lK5IpDB/G/wkjUu0yKGX9rbxenDI\n" \
"U5PMCCjjmCXPI6T53iHTfIUJrU6adTrCC2qJeHZERxhlbI1Bjjt/msv0tadQ1wUs\n" \
"N+gDS63pYaACbvXy8MWy7Vu33PqUXHeeE6V/Uq2V8viTO96LXFvKWlJbYK8U90vv\n" \
"o/ufQJVtMVT8QtPHRh8jrdkPSHCa2XV4cdFyQzR1bldZwgJcJmApzyMZFo6IQ6XU\n" \
"5MsI+yMRQ+hDKXJioaldXgjUkK642M4UwtBV8ob2xJNDd2ZhwLnoQdeXeGADbkpy\n" \
"rqXRfboQnoZsG4q5WTP468SQvvG5\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
//WiFiClientSecure wiFiClient;
void msgReceived(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int len);
//PubSubClient pubSubClient(awsEndpoint, 8883, msgReceived, wiFiClient); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
  Serial.println("Starting...");
  delay(50); Serial.println();
  Serial.println("ESP32 AWS IoT Example");
  Serial.printf("SDK version: %s\n", ESP.getSdkVersion());

 /* Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.print(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  WiFi.waitForConnectResult();
  Serial.print(", WiFi connected, IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  wiFiClient.setCACert(rootCA);// GSM security API or GSM x509 certificate
  wiFiClient.setCertificate(certificate_pem_crt);
  wiFiClient.setPrivateKey(private_pem_key);
*/
```